# Linking Codemirror in-editor changes to p5.js output in a HTML file

Tags: javascript, html, css, p5.js, codemirror

***Problem statement***

I am struggling to understand how to pass the contents of a codemirror editor (when it's updated manually on screen) to a p5.js instance, on a button click.

In other words, how can I refresh and generate a new p5.js instance each time the button is pressed?

***Issue detail***

I've constructed the extremely basic code file below, it's a simple HTML page, which has a loaded Codemirror File.

Every time 'Update Code' is pressed, it prints the current contents of the codemirror instance to the console. However, i'm baffled as to how:

```
          yx = editor.getValue();
          eval(yx);
```

Is not doing anything - theoretically it should output the code segment that has been commented at the bottom of the file (in other words, the current content of the codemirror instance). This output should be generating a 400x400 canvas and an ellipse in the middle.

***Ultimate Aim***
My ultimate aim is quite simple and consists of two parts:

- I would like to have a p5.js output for the initial contents of the
  codemirror instance
- I would like to be able to refresh the p5.js
  output via the button click for any changes made to the codemirror
  instance

***Code***

Please excuse any and all formatting / indenting (please open in codepen or the like):

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.52.2/codemirror.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.52.2/codemirror.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.52.2/mode/javascript/javascript.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet"
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.52.2/theme/dracula.min.css">


<body>
  <font size="1">
    <form>
      <textarea id="jsCode">
      function setup() {
        createCanvas(400, 400);
      }

      function draw() {
        background(220);
        ellipse(200,200,20);
      }
      </textarea>
    </form>
  </font>
</body>

<script id="newx">
        editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById('jsCode'), {
            mode: 'javascript', 
            lineNumbers:true,
            theme: 'dracula',
            electricChars: true,
            scrollbarStyle: "null",
        });
</script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.2.0/p5.min.js"></script>


          <p>Click the button to update</p>

          <button onclick="function2()">Update Code</button>

          <script> 
          function function2() {
          yx = editor.getValue();
          eval(yx);
          console.log(yx);
          };
          </script>

          
          <!-- <script>
              function setup() {
                  createCanvas(400, 400);
                }

              function draw() {
                background(220);
                ellipse(200,200,20);
                }
          </script> -->
```